# Upgrading Entity Framework 1 Project to EF 4

Tags: entity-framework

I currently have a project using EF 1 (.NET 3.5) and would like to move it to the latest and greatest EF version.

I am actually quite happy with the feature set of EF1. The main reason, I want to do this is because I'm moving my frontend from webforms (.NET 3.5) to ASP.NET MVC 3 using Razor as the viewing engine.

I know I can simply change the target framework from 3.5 to 4. But usually these simple upgrade solutions usually result in problems at a later stage. e.g. is there still legacy code in the model? Would I be loosing functionality?

Comment: Do you have any integration tests? In such case you will see it immediately - convert, run tests, check test results.

Comment: @Ladislav, what would you suggest the tests do? Its all well and good saying "make some tests and if it passes then it works!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the migration: 
The migration went really smooth. No hickups whatsoever. Simply upgrade the project and your done.